# Multiple Custom authentication requests to firebase failing

Tags: javascript, callback, firebase, custom-authentication

When trying to get multiple firebase references one after the other, only the last requests callbacks gets called.

Below I am trying to get 3 firebase references for different data

```
console.log('authenticating Users');
var firebaseRef1 = new Firebase('https://stckflw.firebaseio.com/Users');
firebaseRef1.authWithCustomToken('<token>',function(error, authData){
    console.log('authentication callback for Users');
} );
console.log('authenticating Messages');
var firebaseRef2 = new Firebase('https://stckflw.firebaseio.com/Messages');
firebaseRef2.authWithCustomToken('<token>',function(error, authData){
    console.log('authentication callback for Messages');
} );
console.log('authenticating Emails');
var firebaseRef3 = new Firebase('https://stckflw.firebaseio.com/Emails');
firebaseRef3.authWithCustomToken('<token>',function(error, authData){
    console.log('authentication callback for Emails');
} );
```

I am seeing the log like this

authenticating Users
authenticating Messages
authenticating Emails

authentication callback for Emails

Whereas I expect to get all 3 callbacks one after another on authentication, so I expect to see logs like

authenticating Users
authenticating Messages
authenticating Emails

authentication callback for Users
authentication callback for Messages
authentication callback for Emails

Am I missing something here cause of which this happens?

I want to achieve it in such a way that all the callback gets triggered on authentication, without missing any.

I have created a example here http://jsfiddle.net/aniruddhbk/rvkz9mrt/4/

Comment: You can't have multiple authentications at one time. This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What is the end goal here? You probably want to use a single token and set up your security rules to allow wider access, possibly by adding data into Firebase that you can reference from the rules, in order to employ role-based permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since authentication happens asynchronously, these calls are not executing **after** each other, but mostly in parallel. When you start a new authentication call it automatically cancels the existing one. Without understanding much about your use-case, you *can* start each Firebase in its own context/session, by passing an extra (undocumented) parameter in when you create the `Firebase` reference:

```
console.log('authenticating Users');
var firebaseRef1 = new Firebase('https://stckflw.firebaseio.com/Users', 'Users');
firebaseRef1.authWithCustomToken('<token>',function(error, authData){
    console.log('authentication callback for Users');
} );
console.log('authenticating Messages');
var firebaseRef2 = new Firebase('https://stckflw.firebaseio.com/Messages', 'Messages');
firebaseRef2.authWithCustomToken('<token>',function(error, authData){
    console.log('authentication callback for Messages');
} );
console.log('authenticating Emails');
var firebaseRef3 = new Firebase('https://stckflw.firebaseio.com/Emails', 'Emails');
firebaseRef3.authWithCustomToken('<token>',function(error, authData){
    console.log('authentication callback for Emails');
} );
```

This will allow each call to complete and gives you three concurrent authenticated sessions in one Firebase client.

```
authenticating Users
authenticating Messages
authenticating Emails
authentication callback for Users
authentication callback for Messages
authentication callback for Emails
```

As Kato said: it is probably better to **not** do this and find a way to combine the permissions for all three sessions into a single token/session.