# Authenticating as two clients at once with Firebase

Tags: firebase, karma-runner

I'm working on a client/server game.  Normally the client and server run in two different processes, but I want to test their interaction in a unit test (or I guess you could say integration test) via the Karma test runner.  In order to make that work I believe I'll need to authenticate as both the client and server from the same process.  Is there a way to do this?  Below is some code showing what I want to do.  Right now the client authentication seems to remove the server authentication.

```
var server_ref = new Firebase('https://cardbrew-staging.firebaseio.com');
var token = 'mysecuritytoken';
server_ref.authWithCustomToken(token, function(error, authData) {
  console.log('server authed, listening to queue...');
  server_ref.child('user-queue').on('child_added', function(snap) {
    console.log('user entered queue:', snap.key());
  });
});

var client_ref = new Firebase('https://cardbrew-staging.firebaseio.com');
client_ref.authAnonymously(function(error, authData) {
  var user_id = authData.uid;
  console.log('client authed, user_id:', user_id);
  client_ref.child('user-queue').child(user_id).set(true);
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372396/multiple-custom-authentication-requests-to-firebase-failing

Comment: Also, for the benefit of others attempting to apply this to multiple auth scenarios (not specifically for the testing scenario requested here), see [this answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/9n26blpr_VY/eCWZsAMFDAAJ). Generally, let Firebase enforce authentication instead of trying to hack your server to impersonate users.