# Is firebase authentication requests throttled?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a react app that loads multiple components on the page. Each component is authenticated before it is rendered.

https://github.com/amjith/simple-react-app

The authentication is done via Firebase using a decorator that I wrote:

https://github.com/amjith/simple-react-app/blob/master/login-decorator.js

It is used as follows:

https://github.com/amjith/simple-react-app/blob/master/small-component.js#L4

But when I load the page only one of the component renders and the other component says it is still loading. The promise that was returned by `firebase.authWithCustomToken()` never resolves for the component that is unrendered.

If firebase api sdk is doing some caching then it should at least honor all the callbacks and resolve the promises.

I wonder why this isn't working.

Comment: How many simultaneous requests to that domain you have? Is the request  for the widget that is not resolved even sent? Is the response received?

Comment: There can be at most one pending auth request. Starting a second request while one is still pending, will cancel the first request. If that doesn't explain the behavior you see, provide an MCVE in the question please.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372396/multiple-custom-authentication-requests-to-firebase-failing

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You're right. I was loading multiple widgets in the page and each one would fire off a auth request to firebase. I wanted a way to authenticate before rendering it. The github link is a mcve react app that can reproduce this issue.